# pstricks no ticks doesn't work

Tags: graphics, pstricks, plot, pst-plot

I want to remove the ticks in pstricks plot which does not work. I tried:

```
\begin{pspicture}
\psaxes[ticks=none](0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)
\end{pspicture}
```

And got:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none](0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)
```

see documentation of `pst-plot`

Comment: Thank you. But what is the exact difference between ticks and labels?

Comment: ticks are the short lines and labels are the numbers or whatever.